# How to know if my mouse is installed?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, device-manager

I caught a cab to work this morning and I'm not sure if i left my mouse inside. I can remote into my home machine from work but I'm not sure how to ascertain whether my mouse is still plugged in. I had it charging just before I left via one of the USB ports.

So not sure if I just took off without it or took it and left it in the taxi. I was rummaging around in my bag and *think* I remember  taking something out while in the cab.

Monday mornings aey?

I can see 3 HID compliant mouse under mice and keyboard but none of them are identified as Logitech G700s, they are all listed as Microsoft drivers... which might makes sense sense it was plug and play.

How do I query machine for make and model of attached pointing devices to be sure my Logitech mouse is installed?

Comment: Unless the mouse uses something fancier than RF communication, I don't think you will have much luck.

Comment: I believe that if you can get the GUI through your remote, you could install the Logitech drivers and see what's detected.  I haven't installed those drivers for some time, but last time I did it showed the attached devices there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the **Device Manager** and go to **View -> Show hidden devices** you can find the driver of your mouse and if the icon is half-faded to white (or **right click -> Properties**) you will see if it's **unplugged**. If it's not installed you won't find its driver at all.

Edit: Oh you see 3.. I didn't read that, sorry.

I have a USB wireless mouse and it's listed as USB Human Interface Device, do you have one that says USB?

Comment: Thanks, I get this "Currently, this hardware device is not connected to this computer". So thats the answer... but not the result I was looking for. Thx.

Comment: No, ur right showing hidden devices shows up all my logitech receivers and rechargable gaming mouse. But they are all faded and in properties I get the message as above.